# Trying to run website a php file is blank

Tags: php

I have a local copy of a website I am working on and I just found that the index.php files are almost empty. They contain only an opening php tag followed by a commend that says: "Silience is golden."

This is the strangest thing, why could this be and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Its normal.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal and expected inside the `wp-content`, `themes`, and `plugins` directories. Their presence is to prevent listing of directory contents if people navigate to those directories via http. There's nothing wrong there and no fix is required.

Comment: More Info: I found out I needed to contact my web admin to get the code for the root index.php file. He said the files show up blank (even the ones that require some code to make the site work) as a security measure for when websites allow file browsing by default.